# how to use ctrl + mouse click to deselect tree label in angular-tree-control

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tree

I want to use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + mouse click to deselect tree label with using `angular-tree-control`. Simplly, a second click can deselect the tree label. With Checked the `angular-tree-control` API in GitHub, I didn't find any ways to make it. How can I fix the problem?

```
<treecontrol class="tree-light" on-selection="onClickNode(node)" 
 data-tree-model="treeData" selected-node="selectedNode" expanded-
 nodes="expandedTreeData">{{node.label}}
</treecontrol>
```

Comment: May you share samples of your code?

Comment: you can create a recursive function to unselect all childrens.